Which is the right statistical test to do (repeated measure - multiple subjects)?
Objective:
To evaluate the effect of a training intervention on the performance of 6 independent subjects over 8 sessions.
Study Design:
Subjects: 6 independent subjects.
Sessions: Each subject undergoes 8 sessions of evaluation.
Evaluations:
Each session consists of a pre-evaluation, a training intervention, and a post-evaluation.
The sessions are distributed on different days for each subject.
The days since the very first session are recorded for each session.
Research Questions:
Trend Analysis: Determine if the pre-evaluation scores are increasing over the 8 sessions.
Intervention Effect: Determine if the difference between post-evaluation and pre-evaluation scores is statistically significant across all sessions.
Data Characteristics:
Each subject has different intervals between sessions.
The subjects are independent.
The pre- and post-evaluation measurements within each session and throughout the sessions are not independent since the subject repeats the same pre- and post-evaluation.
SO, how should I proceed in this case?


mixed linear model

DATA TESTED  (EACH ROW IS A SUBJECT)
CoverageInitEval =
|61.00|   60.50|   61.00|   56.00|   56.75|   64.50|   62.25|  66.75|
|51.75|   52.75|   65.50|   39.75|   62.50|   55.75|   54.25|  75.00|
|55.00|   60.50|   73.00|   71.50|     NaN|     NaN|     NaN|    NaN|
|27.25|   22.00|   37.50|   42.00|   17.50|   42.00|   46.75|  41.25|
|80.75|   77.25|   70.25|   80.25|   73.25|   77.25|   74.00|  79.00|
|50.00|   56.25|   74.00|   70.50|   76.00|   77.00|   78.25|  79.50|
(EACH ROW IS A SUBJECT AND A COLUMN A DAY)
days =
 0     3     6    14    17    21    24    28
 0     4     8    11    14    21    29    36
 0     7    46    64   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 0     3     6    10    15    24    25    35
 0     4     9    11    14    15    17    19
 0     2     5     7     9    12    14    15

Size of subject_ids: 48
Size of time_points: 48
Size of performance_values: 48
Linear mixed-effects model fit by ML
Model information:
Number of observations              44
Fixed effects coefficients           2
Random effects coefficients         12
Covariance parameters                4
Formula:
Performance ~ 1 + Time + (1 + Time | SubjectID)
Model fit statistics:
AIC      BIC       LogLikelihood    Deviance
379.6    390.31    -183.8           367.6
Fixed effects coefficients (95% CIs):
Name                   Estimate    SE         tStat     DF    pValue        Lower       Upper
{'(Intercept)'}         57.659      3.5076    16.438    42    6.6405e-20       50.58     64.738
{'Time'       }        0.19031     0.18182    1.0467    42       0.30121    -0.17661    0.55723
Random effects covariance parameters (95% CIs):
Group: SubjectID (6 Levels)
Name1                  Name2                  Type            Estimate      Lower    Upper
{'(Intercept)'}        {'(Intercept)'}        {'std' }        1.6837e-07    NaN      NaN
{'Time'       }        {'(Intercept)'}        {'corr'}          -0.99978    NaN      NaN
{'Time'       }        {'Time'       }        {'std' }        1.3657e-08    NaN      NaN
Group: Error
Name               Estimate    Lower     Upper
{'Res Std'}        15.774      12.799    19.439
P-value for Time effect: 0.3012
There is no significant improvement in performance over time.

A linear mixed model would be my first option. Do you have some data to share?

I used that formula that you can see in the last part of the question
